# Fixing NTFS on SSD after corruption by windows cache

Tags: windows-10, ssd, ntfs, cache, filesystem-corruption

This must be a well known issue, so I'm looking for a fix if it exists.
I'm using windows 10. I had an SSD in my desktop that had an NTFS partition with no files.
I shut down the PC, removed the disk and brought it to a data recovery shop to copy my recovered files (from an old HDD).
Then I brought it back home and re-installed it in the same PC and booted into windows 10 again. (I did not boot the PC with the disk removed).

Now I don't see any of the recovered files that they copied to the NTFS partition on the disk. But I do see the space used by the files which matches what they copied.

The data recovery shop say that it's a know behavior of windows where it's caching FS state (if one has not booted it without the disk before re-installing it) and that now the file system is corrupted. So I'll have to go back to copy the data once again.

I wonder if there's a way to fix the NTFS partition to save time driving to the data recovery again.

Comment: Is the SSD the data was recover *to* the same as they recovered data *from*? If so I wouldn't attempt in situ fixes, because if the fix makes matters worse, recovering the data again would become more involved or even impossible. Or to rephrase, I can not quite follow your story.

Comment: No, it was from an HDD, they still have the data so I can go and re-copy it from them if I cannot fix the file system on the SSD.

Comment: So this is secondary SSD, you can still boot? Can you remove drive letter in disk management, reboot and re-assign it? Or just reboot FTM. Then, you could also try chkdsk x: (replace x: by drive letter of SSD, no parameters, so scan only initially.

Comment: Have you done a cold restart (shutdown followed by boot) ?

Comment: @harrymc, yes, I did shut down and boot after that.

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, removing the drive letter, rebooting and adding another drive letter didn't help, still seeing no files but space occupied as before.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, running chkdsk /F X: (in safe mode, but probably would work in regular mode) did it. Thanks! You can post it as an answer if you want.

Comment: Good to know. Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try in this order:

- Remove drive letter in disk management, reboot and re-assign it.
- Run chkdsk without switches to simply scan
- If chkdsk detects issues run with /f switch

I am usually not a fan of chkdsk to restore access to data, but knowing the company has a copy of the data, why not.